# AspectJ-for-NetBeans and the exception: ClassFormatException thrown: File: 'java/lang/CharSequence.class'

Tags: java, netbeans, aspectj

I am trying to use the plugin [AspectJ-for-Netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56882/aspectj-for-netbeans-umuc-swen-670).

But I got this exception. What probability should be ? I did correctly [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgF_5bRH9-Q).

```
Message: ClassFormatException
thrown: File: 'java/lang/CharSequence.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18
Stack trace: org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException:
File: 'java/lang/CharSequence.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:261)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:162)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:384)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:338)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:378)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:271)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:191)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:107)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:46)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:707)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getDeclaredInterfaces(BcelObjectType.java:201)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredInterfaces(ReferenceType.java:430)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDirectSupertypes(ResolvedType.java:65)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.collectInterTypeMungers(ResolvedType.java:1156)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getInterTypeMungersIncludingSupers(ResolvedType.java:1135)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.checkInterTypeMungers(ResolvedType.java:1202)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.weaveInterTypeDeclarations(AjLookupEnvironment.java:643)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.weaveInterTypeDeclarations(AjLookupEnvironment.java:519)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(AjLookupEnvironment.java:1060)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:480)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:190)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:111)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:43)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:87)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(BinaryTypeBinding.java:757)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.methods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:740)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Annotation.resolveType(Annotation.java:227)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ASTNode.resolveAnnotations(ASTNode.java:436)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.EclipseSourceType.getAnnotationTypes(EclipseSourceType.java:692)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.EclipseSourceType.isAnnotationStyleAspect(EclipseSourceType.java:149)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.EclipseSourceType.isAspect(EclipseSourceType.java:128)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAspect(ReferenceType.java:159)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.verifyAnyTypeParametersMeetBounds(AjLookupEnvironment.java:269)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(AjLookupEnvironment.java:228)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:301)
    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:315)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performCompilation(AjBuildManager.java:906)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.doBuild(AjBuildManager.java:260)
    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:176)
    at org.aspectj.ajde.internal.CompilerAdapter.compile(CompilerAdapter.java:107)
    at org.aspectj.ajde.internal.AspectJBuildManager$CompilerThread.run(AspectJBuildManager.java:191)
```

Comment: I have just fixed your question's formatting. Please learn how to use code formatting on StackOverflow. Thanks. Please also show your code, not just the error message. And please provide details about your configuration such as Java and AspectJ version used.

Comment: Thank you ! I am new here. I will put more informations about the problens on the next time.

Comment: No, not next time, this time, please. Just click "edit" and add the additional information.